# recursive finding longest path of same element in 2d list

Tags: python

I need to find the longest path of 0's in a 2d matrix recursively and can't figure out how to do it.( from a given (i , j) it can only move up, down, right or left)

For example this matrix:

```
mat = [[1, 0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 3, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 3]]
    print(question3_b(mat))
```

This should return 6 as there are communities of sizes 1,3,6.
My attempt: I created a few wrapper functions to find the maximum in a list, and a function to find the route at a given (i,j) element and add it to a list, and doing this on every point(i,j) in the matrix.

```py
def question3_b(mat) -> int:
    rows: int = len(mat)
    cols: int = len(mat[0])
    community_lengths = list()
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            visited = zeros(rows, cols)  # create a 2d list of 0's with size rows,cols
            a = findcommunity(mat, (i, j), visited)
            print("a=", a)
            community_lengths.append(a)
    print(community_lengths)
    return findmax(community_lengths)


def findcommunity(mat: list, indices: tuple, visited: list):  # find length of community
    #global rec_counter
    #rec_counter += 1
    i, j = indices
    rows = len(mat)
    cols = len(mat[0])
    if mat[i][j] == 0:
        visited[i][j] = 1
        if i < rows - 1:
            if visited[i + 1][j] == 0:
                return 1 + findcommunity(mat, (i + 1, j), visited)
        if j < cols - 1:
            if visited[i][j + 1] == 0:
                return 1 + findcommunity(mat, (i, j + 1), visited)
        if i > 0:
            if visited[i - 1][j] == 0:
                return 1 + findcommunity(mat, (i - 1, j), visited)
        if j > 0:
            if visited[i][j - 1] == 0:
                return 1 + findcommunity(mat, (i, j - 1), visited)
    else:  # mat[i][j]!=0

        return 0

def zeros(rows:int,cols:int)->list: #create a 2d matrix of zeros with size (rows,cols)
    if rows==1 and cols==1:return [[0]]
    if rows==1 and cols>1:return [[0]*cols]
    if rows>1 and cols>1:return zeros(rows-1,cols)+zeros(1,cols)
def findmax(arr:list)->int: # find max in an array using recursion
    if len(arr)==2:
        if arr[0]>arr[1]:return arr[0]
        else:return arr[1]
    else:
        if arr[0]>arr[1]:
            arr[1]=arr[0]
            return findmax(arr[1:])
        else:
            return findmax(arr[1:])
```

Where did I go wrong? for a matrix of 4X4 zeros, I expect it to run 16*16 times[16 times for each i,j, and there are 16 elements in the matrix]. but it only runs once.
zeros is a recursive function I made that functions like np.zeros, it creates a 2d matrix full of 0's with specified size.

Comment: what exactly do you expect to run 16 times ? you call the main function (question3_b) once. It iterates through the whole grid (once). While doing that it calls the findcommunity function recursivly. do you have more code somewhere ? `rec_counter` is not defined here. `zeros` is `np.zeros` I guess? There is a syntax error, you need to pass the shape of it with a tuple `(rows,cols)`.

Comment: Please type the text instead of posting an image.

Comment: apologies for the vague description, edited.
Yes, zeros functions like np.zeros but done in a recursive manner.

Comment: and i just noticed you should please add the function `findmax` which is in the return statement of your main function.

Comment: For the sake of completeness please add also the zeros function (or anything which we need to run this code). Because I'd say the visited matrix should be created once outside the loop of i and j. like this you create every iteration a full matrix of zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got really messy but I tried to just change your code instead of writing a new solution. You should have a look at `collections deque`. Saw this several times where people keep track of `visited` a lot easier.

I changed visited to outside of the loop and defined it with `np.zeros` (didn't have your function ;) ). I'm not sure if your recursive function calls at return were wrong but your if-statements were, or at least the logic behind it (or I didn't understand, also possible :) )
I changed that block completly. The first time you come across a `0` in `mat` the recursive part will dig into the `mat` as long as it finds another `0` left,right,bottom or top of it (that's the functionality behind `dc` and `dr`). That's where the `community_counter` is increasing. If the function is returning the last time and you jump out to the outerloop in `question_3b` the counter gets resetted and searchs for the next `0` (next start of another community).

```
import numpy as np

def question3_b(mat) -> int:
    rows: int = len(mat)
    cols: int = len(mat[0])
    community_lengths = list()
    visited = np.zeros((rows, cols))  # create a 2d list of 0's with size rows,cols
    community_count = 0
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            if visited[row][col]==0:
                community_count,visited = findcommunity(mat, (row, col), visited, community_count)
                if community_count!=0:
                    community_lengths.append(community_count)
                community_count=0
    return community_lengths


def findcommunity(mat: list, indices: tuple, visited: list,community_count: int):  # find length of community
    i, j = indices
    rows = len(mat)
    cols = len(mat[0])
    visited[i][j] = 1
    if mat[i][j] == 0:
        community_count += 1
        dr = [-1, 0, 1, 0]
        dc = [0,-1, 0, 1]
        for k in range(4):
            rr = i + dr[k]
            cc = j + dc[k]
            if 0<=rr<rows and 0<=cc<cols:
                if visited[rr][cc]==0 and mat[rr][cc]==0:
                    community_count, visited = findcommunity(mat, (rr,cc), visited, community_count)
        return community_count,visited
    else:
        return community_count,visited

mat = [[1, 0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 3, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 3]]

all_communities = question3_b(mat)
print(all_communities)
# [6, 3, 1]
print(max(all_communities))
# 6
```

**EDIT**

Here is the `findcommunity` function in your way. Tested it and it works aswell.

```
def findcommunity(mat: list, indices: tuple, visited: list,community_count: int):  # find length of community
    i, j = indices
    rows = len(mat)
    cols = len(mat[0])
    visited[i][j] = 1
    if mat[i][j] == 0:
        community_count += 1
        if i < rows - 1:
            if visited[i + 1][j] == 0:
                community_count, visited = findcommunity(mat, (i + 1, j), visited, community_count)
        if j < cols - 1:
            if visited[i][j + 1] == 0:
                community_count, visited = findcommunity(mat, (i, j + 1), visited, community_count)
        if i > 0:
            if visited[i - 1][j] == 0:
                community_count, visited = findcommunity(mat, (i - 1, j), visited, community_count)
        if j > 0:
            if visited[i][j - 1] == 0:
                community_count, visited = findcommunity(mat, (i, j - 1), visited, community_count)
        return community_count,visited
    else:
        return community_count,visited
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it does work well,I just need to make the loops recursive.
What made you go with dr,dr over the if conditions I used?

Comment: your welcome. I just did it myself before and remembered kind of how I get it done. edited my answer. It turned out your logic was pretty similar to my approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here a completely different approach, in case someone is interested.

```
import numpy as np

mat = [[1, 0, 0, 3, 0],
         [0, 0, 2, 3, 0],
         [2, 0, 0, 2, 0],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 3]]
mat = np.array(mat)

# some padding of -1 to prevent index error
mask = np.full(np.array(mat.shape) + 2,  -1)
mask[1:-1, 1:-1 ] = mat

# visiteds are set to -2
def trace(f, pt):
    mask[tuple(pt)], pts = -2, [pt - 1]
    pts += [trace(f, pt + d) for d in 
([0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0]) if 
mask[tuple(pt + d)] == f]
    return pts

clusters = lambda f: {tuple(pt-1): trace(f, pt) for pt in np.argwhere(mask==f) if mask[tuple(pt)]==f}

# now call with value your looking for
print(clusters(0))
```